# What is the difference between %{} and %s?

Tags: ruby

In exercise 9 in the Learn Ruby the Hard Way book, I am asked to write the following:

```
formatter = "%{first} %{second} %{third} %{fourth}"
puts formatter % {first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4}
```

which just evaluates to

```
1 2 3 4
```

When searching around, I noticed that many people have written this instead:

```
formatter = "%s %s %s %s"
puts formatter % [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I believe the latter example is from an older version of the book. Can someone explain to me what the differences are between the two examples?

Comment: Former allows naming (and thus reusing) of varibles injected into the string. Latter does not allow this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick answer to that is that the `%{}` syntax allows you to pass in named arguments to be substituted into your string whereas the `%s` syntax only substitutes items in the order they are given.

You can do more things with the `%{}` version, for example if you have the same string you need to substitute in multiple times you could write it out like this:

```
 string = "Hello %{name}, nice to meet you %{name}. Now I have said %{name} three times, I remember your name."
 string % { :name => "Magnus" }
```

With the `%s` syntax, you would have had to write:

```
string = "Hello %s, nice to meet you %s. Now I have said %s three times, I remember your name."
string % ["Magnus", "Magnus", "Magnus"]
```

There are many other formats and ways to write substitutions for strings in Ruby. The full explanation can be found [here in the Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Comment: When I have to pass a value multiple times I use array multiplication: `%w[Magnus] * 3 # => ["Magnus", "Magnus", "Magnus"]` or `['foo', *(%w[bar] * 3), 'foo'] # => ["foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "foo"]`

Comment: @theTinMan That seems like it's over complicating things. I think I'd rather be able to see clearly what was being substituted over working out what an array would be in order to tell how many items needed substituting. And it would avoid any repetition, like the 'foo' in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

```
formatter = "%{first} %{second} %{third} %{fourth}"
```

and

```
formatter = "%s %s %s %s"
```

are essentially the same in that the formatting method will take values and substitute them into a string, however the first format string uses named placeholders vs. unnamed placeholders in the second.

This affects how you pass the values being substituted. The first accepts a hash of symbols, and uses the keys of that hash to identify which of the fields get that associated value. In the second, you pass an array, and the values are picked positionally from the array when being substituted into the format string.

The second is more common, and has been around for years, so you'll see it more often. The first, because it's newer isn't going to run on old Rubies, but has the advantage of resulting in a bit more readable format strings which is good for maintenance. Also, as @griffin says in his comment, the first also allows you to more easily repeat a value if necessary. You can do it when passing an array into the old-style format, but a hash would be more efficient memory-wise, especially for cases when you've got a lot of variables you're reusing.

Note: You'll see `%{foo}f` and `%<foo>f`. There is a difference in how the variable passed in is formatted, so be careful which you use:

```
'%<foo>f' % {:foo => 1} # => "1.000000"
'%{foo}f' % {:foo => 1} # => "1f"
```

I think the difference is too subtle and will cause problems for unaware developers. For more information, see the [Kernel#sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) documentation.